# Батон колбасы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Слово "батон" может применяться к чему-то, кроме хлеба?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Большом толковом словаре зафиксировано, что у слова БАТОН два значения: 1. *Белый хлеб вытянутой формы. Нарезной батон. Купить буханку хлеба и два батона. Нарезать батон для бутербродов.*  2. О пищевом продукте вытянутой формы (обычно округлой). *Батон варёной колбасы.*
Следовательно, это слово может применяться не только по отношению к хлебу. Кстати о сухой колбасе чаще говорят: *палка сыровяленой колбасы.*

Answer (score 1):

Известно, что слово "батон" произошло от французского baton, что обозначает буквально "палка". Думаю, это объясняет правомерность существования словосочетаний "батон колбасы", "палка колбасы"

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта *палка колбасы* мне кажется ненормативной, просторечной. Но и батон про нее не скажешь. Про "закругляющуюся" колбасу я слышала "коляска". Может, кто ответит, как правильно про копчёную колбасу сказать?

Comment: Палка, по-крайней мере, понятно. Если Вас это слово коробит - ну, скажите "штука". Слово стилистически нейтральное. Правда, могут не понять...

Answer (score 0):

В НПА (например ГОСТ Р 52196-2011) закреплен термин "батон" в отношении колбасной продукции, будь то сырокопченая или вареная, также нет отдельных терминов касаемо формы, размера и вязки колбасы (овальный батон, круглый батон, прямой батон).

Answer (score -1):

Мои родители поспорили о том, как нужно говорить: "батон колбасы" или "палка колбасы". Я поискала в "Гугл", и выяснилось, что они оба правы.

Comment: Гугл - не аргумент. На сарае тоже написано.